# best sorting based on comparison of list indexed by integer in the map

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting, dictionary

I want to sort an array which consist of integers which are index of map>, the comparison depends on the list of string in the map corresponding to the integer index,
so which sorting algorithm would be the best, provided that the array can be very huge, considering time as well as memory?

```
public class AuthorSorting {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        int index = 0;
        int array[] = {0, 1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6};
        Map<Integer,List<String>> myMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        myMap.put(index++, Arrays.asList("Abhijit Bhaduri","Kewal Dheer","Hemant Shesh"));
        myMap.put(index++, Arrays.asList("Kewal Dheer","Kiran Desai","Nandini Sahu"));
        myMap.put(index++, Arrays.asList("Abhijit Bhaduri"));
        myMap.put(index++, Arrays.asList("Kewal Dheer","Kiran Desai","Mohan Deep"));
        myMap.put(index++, Arrays.asList("Kewal Dheer"));
        myMap.put(index++, Arrays.asList("Kiran Desai","Mohan Deep","Pawan Karan"));
        myMap.put(index++, Arrays.asList("Hemant Shesh"));
        System.out.println("*****input*****\n");
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry: myMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" "+entry.getValue().toString());
        }
        int temp;
        for(int i = 1 ; i < array.length;i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < array.length-i;j++) {
                    if(compare(myMap.get(array[j]),myMap.get(array[j+1]))<0) {//swapping only if compare() returns -1
                        temp = array[j];
                        array[j] = array[j+1];
                        array[j+1] = temp;
                    }                   
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\n******result*******\n");
        for(int number:array) {
            System.out.println(number+" "+myMap.get(number).toString());
        }
    }
    static int compare(List<String> listOne,List<String> listTwo) {
        int i;
        for(i = 0 ; i<listOne.size()&&i<listTwo.size();i++) {
            if(listOne.get(i).compareToIgnoreCase(listTwo.get(i))>0) {
                return -1;// listOne's string is lexically greater
            }
            else if(listOne.get(i).compareToIgnoreCase(listTwo.get(i))<0) {
                return 1;// listTwo's string is lexically greater
            }
        }
        if(listOne.size()==listTwo.size())
            return 0;
        if(i==listOne.size())
            return 1;
        if(i==listTwo.size())
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }
} 

*****input*****

0 [Abhijit Bhaduri, Kewal Dheer, Hemant Shesh]
1 [Kewal Dheer, Kiran Desai, Nandini Sahu]
2 [Abhijit Bhaduri]
3 [Kewal Dheer, Kiran Desai, Mohan Deep]
4 [Kewal Dheer]
5 [Kiran Desai, Mohan Deep, Pawan Karan]
6 [Hemant Shesh]

******result*******

2 [Abhijit Bhaduri]
0 [Abhijit Bhaduri, Kewal Dheer, Hemant Shesh]
6 [Hemant Shesh]
4 [Kewal Dheer]
3 [Kewal Dheer, Kiran Desai, Mohan Deep]
1 [Kewal Dheer, Kiran Desai, Nandini Sahu]
5 [Kiran Desai, Mohan Deep, Pawan Karan]
```

currently, I've used bubble sort, and not sure enough that it would be efficient with huge arrays

Comment: Parallel arrays are so 1970's, you need to use proper objects and write the required comparator, and use the builtin collection sorting methods.

Comment: Just use `Arrays.sort` with your `Comparator` function.